# Can you flag duplicate if the old question contains an answer which is not answering the old question but answering the new question?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

Sometimes, a question can be misunderstood by someone and resulting a good article but off-topic to the question it is answering. If this answer happens to be a good answer to another question, does this count as duplicated?

Comment: I'd say if the answer is not suitable for the question it was posted on it should probably be deleted and then posted on a suitable question. Closing as duplicate doesn't seem suitable since given that the question does not match the answer, closing it as a duplicate won't help discoverability

Comment: To be closed as a duplicate a question must have an accepted answer or at least one answer with a positive score. I suspect that in such a scenario the other question would therefore not be a valid sure candidate, as the wrong (but good) answer is unlikely to have a positive score or it will be targetable, however, the answer wanted would be near the end (assuming sorted by score).

Comment: There is a good chance such an answer will be deleted. Even if it would be technically a duplicate for a bit, it won’t be for long.

Comment: Answers that are answers won't be deleted, @MisterMiyagi.

Comment: @CodeCaster Answers that don’t address the question are regularly downvoted and often deleted by the author.

Comment: I think what @CodeCaster means to say is that you should not *flag* such answers using the "not an answer" flag, as that is not an appropriate route for getting them deleted. My question is, is this is a contrived scenario, or did you actually see this happen? How did this "answer that happens to be a good answer to another question but [i]s off-topic to the question is answering" get posted in the first place?

Comment: @CodyGray I came across the question [Creating Minesweeper using only JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276987/creating-minesweeper-using-only-javascript/76277907#76277907) and someone in comment suggesting [Minesweeper solving algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738128/minesweeper-solving-algorithm), which contains an answer for creating the game. What get more complicated is that the "old question" OP did ask for how to build the game, despite the title asking for a solving algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, when a question attracts an "off-topic" answer that isn't immediately downvoted, this is a sign that the question itself is problematic - it was either unfocused (a common case for old questions is that someone simply straight up asked two questions, and different answers addressed each; sometimes, one of the questions gets edited away later by curators because it appears incidental to the "main" question) or unclear (there are answers to different questions because different people read the same text and understood a different question from it).

Therefore, the question should not be used as a duplicate target for anything.

Some exception can be made for deliberately crafted canonicals, where an expert in the field (sometimes a joint effort between "regulars") has identified a well-defined "topic" that nevertheless *could be* divided into separate questions by someone with the motivation to do so. For example, it could have been crafted specifically to [avoid having a pair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426162) of "what does X do? it does Y / how do I do Y? use X" questions; or to explain how even though a given error message (or kind of error message) could have multiple distinguishable causes, or even appear in seemingly different contexts, it all all [boils down to the *same conceptual misunderstanding*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420096).

But as an exception to the exception, such canonicals [should not just "roll up" a bunch of simple questions with a similar form when a separate explanation is necessary for each"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427530). Such ["signposts"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418516) can be useful for *finding* the right duplicate target, but should not themselves be used to close other questions as duplicates.