# How should we deal with "tool/technique -> problem" and "problem -> tool/technique" question pairs?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are a ton of old pairs of questions I've noticed on Stack Overflow of the general form:

> Q1. When would I use X rather than Y?
>
> A1. In situation S, using Y naively would cause a problem P. Using X instead is the primary intended way to work around the problem, rather than fixing the use of Y.

> Q2. I'm in situation S. I tried to use Y, but problem P occurred. How do I fix it?
>
> A2. You should use X instead - that's precisely what it's for. (Alternately, you can work around it like so, but the entire reason X exists is to do that for you.)

Here's a textbook motivating example I just came across:

Q1: [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405)

Q2: [Return a default value if a dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768)

I contend that pairs like this are really fundamentally asking the same question. I [have in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419863/editing-old-questions-to-add-links-to-similar-ones/419864#419864) cross-linked these with a "See also" note, and just did so this time as well; but should we do anything more?

Comment: Link to it via a comment and provide an answer

Comment: I think everywhere outside the Python tag the first type of questions would be considered too broad (with the second being *the way* to ask it)... But I'm not an expert in that tag so no recommendations how to handle such cases there.

Comment: Personally I don't prefer questions of the form "What's the difference between X and Y?" IMO questions of this form can generally be two different questions asking about X and Y each.

Comment: FWIW, I have encountered many people that could not have answered the first question and would never have thought that the second was even sensible to ask, as well as various permutations of misunderstanding or not knowing either of the pair. Don’t underestimate the power of cargo culting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*sigh*

In a perfect world people would just read the fabulous manual and we would not need either question. Knowing how one question translates to the other would allow them to realise the answer themselves and - poof - both questions are gone.

Sadly, evidence strongly suggests this is not the world in which SO exists. People do ask both questions, people do need answers to both questions; they do this precisely because they lack the knowledge to realise the overlap.

Yes, cross-linking them - via comments, edits or otherwise - offers useful information for the moment after things have \*click\*ed. Yet this is it and we must resist the urge to go further such as closing as duplicates.